# Java stream run atleast once

Tags: java, foreach, stream

I have a list: `List<Filter>`. I want to make a call to a downstream API which can only take a single `Filter` in it's request. So I can do something like this:

```
filters.forEach(filter -> callAPI(someId, filter);
```

The problem with this is if the filters are empty, I won't even make a single call to the API. To solve this I tried something like this:

```
if (filters.isEmpty()) {
    callAPI(someId, null);
} else {
    filters.forEach(filter -> callAPI(someId, filter);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: I wouldn't flag this in a code review- the example is clear in it's intent, so it's a winner

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" way? Your current way is good enough.

Comment: I was looking for something using streams which could directly do this and remove the if block

Comment: With streams, this would be more complicated and harder to read.  You'll still have to encode the conditional logic somehow, which is nastier with streams.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
List<Filter> filters = ...
if (filters.isEmpty()) {
    filters = Collections.singleton(null);
}
filters.forEach(filter -> callAPI(someId, filter));
```

Difference: processing is done after the if, so that callAPI is called from a single location.